# Controlling ListView preview items number in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have a `ListView` which would usually only display 1-3 items at runtime, but Android Studio fills it with 24, making it overtake the whole layout. If I want to see the rest of the layout I have to either comment it out or set its visibility to gone. Is there a way I can make Android Studio only render a couple of items so my other views in the layout will be visible in the designer?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it by adding this to the ListView definition:

```
tools:layout_height="350dip"
```

If you're using a RecyclerView, you could do it much better:

```
tools:itemCount="3"
```

Both arguments are only applied in the Android Studio preview, not in the app itself, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.

Comment: Right. And you can even use: ```tools:listitem="@layout/your_adapter"``` to have a correct preview of the items in your RecyclerView

Comment: `tools:listitem` does not only work for RecyclerView but also for ListView.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming right now your ListView has a height that wraps content, which means it will be as long as it can to display everything. If you want to limit it, it you can give it a specific dp height or you can give it a gravity (to make it say half the screen).

Comment: I don't want to limit it, I only want to change the number of mock items shown in the Android Studio designer.

Comment: Can you add a picture to illustrate what you mean?